# Need help sizing Zener diodes and varistor for 12V automotive power supply protection

Tags: power-supply, automotive

I have built an astable 555 timer circuit to control a MAC valve that will allow me to change the turbo charger boost levels on my S10.

The circuit works great as is but I skimped on the circuit protection side of it.  Currently there is a diode across the MAC valve and just a single .33 uF capacitor on the 12V side of the LM2937-5V voltage regulator.

[image]

After doing some research it looks like I should consider installing both a varistor and a Zener diode to help protect against voltage spikes.

Here are some good articles I found:

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/transient-suppression.html

https://www.electronicdesign.com/power-management/article/21800530/select-the-right-varistors-for-overvoltage-circuit-protection

Here is a link at Mouser of some varistors I am looking at
https://www.mouser.com/Circuit-Protection/Varistors/Automotive-series/_/N-5g3h?P=1yzt5irZ1y7yila

Running voltage is around 14 volts.  According to the document above I should size for 20% over so I should look at around 17 volts.

What should I consider for peak current in an automotive environment?

Is the only reason to consider a varistor with a lower peak surge current just physical size?  So if I had all the room in the world then I just go with a 2kA and be done?

Another item I have been using for some back ground information is the schematics for a MegaSquirt ECU.  For those of you that are not familiar with MegaSquirt ECUs they come as DIY ECU kits that you solder together and assemble based on your engine's needs.

Here is the schematic of the voltage regulator and circuit protection.
I guess my question is what is the difference between MOV1 and the D13/D11/D12 combo.  I thought a MOV essentially acted like a back to back Zener diode package.

[image]

I guess can someone help kick me in the right direction.
What exactly am I trying to protect against?  Someone hooking 2 batteries in series?  Hooking up jumper cables backwards?  Large rush of current during cranking?

Comment: Protection is against all you mentioned.  || MOVs are fast but use up some lifetime every time they absorb energy.  MOV direct at source may have a brutal life in an autoenvironment. Or not. A little prioe R may help lifetime. || Zener as shown dies-ish as no series R except wiring. Work out worst case regulator Vin at max current out and worst case spec sheet dropout at that current. Work out worst case LOWEST V12 that you want supply to hold up at (maybe 12V maybe less. Cranking may be hard and a large cap will help holdup. THEN a series R = Rs will drop (Vin-MIN - V_Reg_In_MAX) = Vr.

Comment: Zener is set to hold Vin_Reg to MAX safe level less a bit . | Rs = Vr/reg_Imax. Pzener = (Vinmax-Vzener) /Rs x Vz + a bit. Vinmax is under fault or spike and is short term. eg if you can have 2 x Vbat = say 24V for 1s and zener = 15V and Rs = SAY 10 Ohms (example only_ then Pz for 1s = Iz x Vz = (Vin-Vz)/Rs x Vz = (24-15)/10 x 15 = 1.35W. So eg a 2W zener will handle this easily and a 5W or 10W zener will handle MUCH larger peaks "for a while" . Power in Rs = (I_max_Rs )^2 x Rs = later ...

Answer (score 2):

Protection is against all you mentioned, **plus Murphy**.

MOVs are fast but use up some lifetime every time they absorb energy.
MOV direct at source may have a brutal life in an autoenvironment. Or not. 
A little prior resistance may help lifetime.

Zeners operated well inside specs have long lifetimkes.
Zener as shown dies-ish as no series R except wiring.
Work out

- worst case regulator Vin
- at max current out and
- worst case spec sheet dropout at that current.
- worst case LOWEST V12 that you want supply to hold up at (maybe 12V maybe less.

  - Cranking may be hard and a large cap will help holdup.

**THEN** a series R = Rs will drop
Vdrop = (Vin-MIN - V_Reg_In_MAX) = Vr.
Zener is set to hold Vin_Reg to MAX safe level less a bit.
Rs = Vr/reg_Imax.
Pzener = (Vinmax-Vzener) / Rs x Vz + a bit.
Vinmax is under fault or spike and is short term.
eg if you can have 2 x Vbat = say 24V for 1s and zener = 15V and Rs = SAY 10 Ohms (example only_
then Pz for 1s = Iz x Vz
= (Vin-Vz)/Rs x Vz
= (24-15)/10 x 15
= 1.35W.

So eg a 2W zener will handle this easily and a 5W or 10W zener will handle MUCH larger peaks "for a while" .

Power in Rs = (I_max_Rs )^2 x Rs = later ...

E&OE

Comment: Something I should have mentioned since it takes out the cranking part. This circuit is powered off of a pressure switch. So the circuit only turns out after the turbo has reached 3psi. So really the circuit only runs while the engine is in the 4000-7000 rpm range. The 555 timer circuit and valve together only pull about 700ma.

Comment: @zildjian4life218 OK. Zener is still not a terrible idea. All the above looks complex, but essentially it just says - add a series R and a zener that clamps spikes to under regulator may Vin and of of sufficient power rating to not die under spike energy. Probably a 2.7 Ohm resistor, 5W 12V zener and maybe a larger C16 should be about OK. Overall itr may work OK as is.

Comment: since the voltage regulator is only rated for up to 18V should I use an 18v zener diode or go a little higher like a 20 or 22v?

Comment: @zildjian4life218 Somewhat lower that the regulator Vmaxin to allow the zener to get a good "bite" on nay peak while still inside regulator rating. Say 15V. If you have a series R and are dropping some voltage across it then even a 12V zener will be OK and not usually conducting.

Answer (score 0):

This may be too late, but the question and answers are going in the wrong direction.

Inductive load & wiring and a very hard switch turn off of 0.035Ω produces V=LdI/dt which cannot be clamped by a 1N400x diode as it's bulk ESR resistance is at least 10x higher than the FET.  a higher current diode would be better as the conduction resistance drops for higher current ratings. R=Vf/I @ 25'C junction temp.

Also several caps of higher value with low ESR and smaller value are needed to help snub the risetime dI/dt and thus also reduce the voltage and ripple.

Layout of the current area of this current loop also affects the radiated noise for interference so tight wiring in a small layout and twisted pairs are advised.